# Get alert content when alert is shown

Tags: c#, javascript, html, vb.net, winforms

I have an HTML page with this script:

```
<Script>
function Run()
{
alert("The Content Here");
return true;
}
</script>
<button onclick="Run();">I Want It Now</button>
```

Lets say that I opened this page with **firefox** or **Chrome**. And lets say that I clicked on the button "I Want It Now" and the page shows me the alert:

```
The Content Here
```

How can I insert the alert content into a string in my VB.NET project? I know that I can use the alert window handle to get the label handle and then extract (grab) the text of the alert, but I don't think that this is the best way to do it. Is there another way to pass (or get) information from the page (not from **webbrowser control** or by using  **webClient.DownloadString**) into my VB.NET (or C#) project?

Comment: You want to be able to use the inserted(?) value in code-behind?

Comment: @Constanta Im Using WinForms, Not Aspx.Net - I Want To Extract Information From The Alert(Of Any Page - Using FireFox Or Chrome)

Comment: ok so you want your app to get a value from firefox or chrome? if yes this is out of my league.

Answer (score 0):

i don't this it will easy to use js without the webbrowser control by the way if you changed your mind and want to use a web browser control , you can do it like this :)

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("NAME").InvokeMember("click");
```